# My Joomla Template is loading my custom CSS using JS. Is there a way to add the unique version tag to my custom CSS? i.e: custom.css?20180101

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, joomla

I normally just add my unique tag to the css path in the  section of my html, but my template is adding my custom CSS via Javascript:

```
if (is_file(T3_TEMPLATE_PATH . '/css/custom.css')) {
$this->addStyleSheet(T3_TEMPLATE_URL . '/css/custom.css');
}
```

I tried adding the unique tag to the above, but it doesn't work:

```
if (is_file(T3_TEMPLATE_PATH . '/css/custom.css')) {
$this->addStyleSheet(T3_TEMPLATE_URL . '/css/custom.css?20180101');
}
```

I inspected my web page and it still spits out:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".../css/custom.css">
```

Comment: Please include how you "tried adding the unique tag to the above" and exactly how "it doesn't work". Once you can compose a clarified question, please post your Joomla questions on Joomla Stack Exchange.

Comment: My apologies. I have edited my post and hope I have provided more clarity. I will post on Joomla Stack Exchange too.

Comment: Dear Joomla researchers, this question has received high quality advice and solution @ https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/24043/12352

Answer (score 0):

The above code again works stored cache for same file name, but you want each page request new file name randomly,so you can use the below code was perfectly suite for you.

```
if (is_file(T3_TEMPLATE_PATH . '/css/custom.css')) {
   $this->addStyleSheet(T3_TEMPLATE_URL . '/css/custom.css?'.rand());
}
```